# How to create equivalent SQL Server database in powershell as SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

Below is a picture of the exact configuration for a database I'd like to create. It's just from connecting to the server, going to the 'Databases' tab seen on the left, right clicking 'New Database...' and then just naming the database 'test' and clicking 'OK'.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbwOY.png

There isn't any documentation online about how to mimic this behavior and most SQL database creations via powershell point to a *.sql file, which in this case doesn't seem to exist (at least not explicitly through the SQL Server Management Studio application). How can I make this 'blank' database in Powershell the same way as it is created through the application?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: There is in fact loads of documentation, the SQL server `create database` statement is well documented.

Comment: @DaleK I've searched in the system for the .mdf and .ldf files to use as defaults in the CREATE DATABASE sql command parameters, but I haven't been able to find them. Is it just model.mdf and modellog.ldf to use? And then I can follow https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6223/create-sql-server-database-with-powershell/

Comment: There are a load of examples in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=sqlpool) showing how to set filenames etc.

Comment: There is the `script` button. Click the arrow to see options and examine the scripts it generates.

Comment: DbaTools module and the `New-DbaDatabase` command https://docs.dbatools.io/New-DbaDatabase

Comment: Best way is to deaatch the database from the server.  Then copy the mdf file in windows to a new filename.  Then attached the new and old databases.  The attach command gives option to make the display name anything you want.  You can't copy the mdf file while it is attach to server because the server owns the file.